# Spaces Between Columns

Tags: r, dataframe

When I print my data frame, there are two columns with a bunch of white space in between them, and the column next to it is crammed right next to the one on the right.

It basically looks like this:

```
c1 c2  (whitespace) c3c4 c5
```

How can I fix this? Is there a formatting option?

The column names are no longer than the data within the columns, so that's not the reason for the white space. Sorry if the image is unclear but I'm new here and am not very familiar with formatting.

Comment: It is most likely that one of your columns actually has tons of whitespace in the actual data.

Comment: What is the class of each of those variables (ie, what does `sapply( yourdataframe, class)` return?). If `c2` is a character, what is `max(nchar(yourdataframe$c2))`. And how did you import your data?

Comment: @MrFlick keeping my notation, c2=character, c3=character, c4=date. max(nchar) = 6; I imported by read.delim through a large .txt file

Comment: ah, I found the problem - it turns out max(nchar) is large for c3, it has one rogue element. Although I'd assume that would create whitespace between c3 and c4, not c2 and c3. Thanks for the method!

Comment: I'm glad you got it. I can never remember if column names are right or left aligned.

Answer (score 0):

If excessive whitespace exists in a column, it's fairly simple to clean it up.  R has a great variety of text manipulation functions.  Take this example.

```
> x <- c("this        is     ", "a        column with   ",
         "     a lot of ", "            whitespace")
> (d <- data.frame(w = 1:4*100, x = x, y = 1:4*10))
    w                       x  y
1 100     this        is      10
2 200 a        column with    20
3 300               a lot of  30
4 400              whitespace 40
```

In package `stringr`, `str_trim()` removes the whitespace from either (or both) end(s) of a string, and `str_replace()` can be used to replace the other space characters with a single space.

```
> library(stringr)
> dd <- data.frame(sapply(d, function(x){
      str_replace(str_trim(x), "\\s+", " ")
      })))
    w             x  y
1 100       this is 10
2 200 a column with 20
3 300      a lot of 30
4 400    whitespace 40
```

**ADDED :** Per your question in the comments regarding centering the column name, yes, we can do that by padding the relevant element in the names vector using the `str_pad()` function from the same package.

```
> num <- floor(max(nchar(as.character(dd$x)))/2)
> names(dd)[2] <- str_pad(names(dd)[2], num, "right")
> dd
    w        x       y
1 100       this is 10
2 200 a column with 20
3 300      a lot of 30
4 400    whitespace 40
```

Comment: thanks! also, is there a way to center the column names, so that the "x" label would be halfway between "w" and "y"?

Comment: @pwerth I added that in at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

This would work (.i.e. remove leading or trailing spaces) for character and factor vectors. It's a simplified combined version of the `gdata:::trim.character` and `gdata:::trim.factor` functions:

```
trim <- function (s ) 
{   s <- as.character(s)
    s <- sub(pattern = "^[[:blank:]]+", replacement = "", x = s)
    s <- sub(pattern = "[[:blank:]]+$", replacement = "", x = s)
    s
}
```

Credit: pkg:gdata is authored maintained by Greg Warnes